# JavaScript regex match anything except a letter

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to match the specific string that comes after "testing"

- provided that there is one (so avoiding matching "testing" alone)
- and avoiding the match if that string is specifically the letter "L"

Like this

```
testing rest -> matches (rest)
testing what -> matches (what)
testing Loong -> matches (Loong)
testing N -> matches (N)
testing L -> this is not matched
testing LL -> matches (LL)
testing J -> matches (J)
testing -> this is not matched
testing -> this is not matched
testing L TY -> this specific string will not occur so it is irrelevant
```

and with quotes

```
"testing rest" -> matches (rest)
"testing what" -> matches (what)
"testing Loong" -> matches (Loong)
"testing N" -> matches (N)
"testing L" -> this is not matched
"testing LL" -> matches (LL)
"testing J" -> matches (J)
"testing" -> this is not matched
"testing "-> this is not matched
"testing L TY" -> this specific string will not occur so it is irrelevant
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Maybe [`/^"?testing (.{2,}?)"?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/wI8cY2/2)?

Comment: Well, maybe [`/^"?testing ((?!\s*L?\s*$).*?)"?$/`](https://regex101.com/r/wI8cY2/3)?

Comment: `/^"(testing(?: )?.*)"$/` - https://regex101.com/r/cW1dK1/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seems to work, if you could explain a little bit the chain ...

Comment: @SebastianProske I think it is clear in the (updated) question (?), I want to match (here test for simplicity) the text after "testing" if there is a text and if this is not the letter L

Comment: I provided an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
/^testing ([^L]|..+)$/
```

or, if You can not remove quotation marks before matching:

```
/^"?testing ([^L"]|.[^"]+)"?$/
```

Explaination:

First part: **^testing** searches for constant element of Your strings - this is easy part.

Then, there is [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) (in round brackets): **[^L]|..+** which consists of *OR* statement (a pipe).

On the left side of this *OR* we have a search pattern for all one character strings (except for letter "*L*"). It is done be defining set (using square brackets **[]**), and negation (using this sign: **^**, which means negation when it is first sign in square brackets).

On the right side we have search pattern for anything that is at lease two chars long. This is done by fisrt matching anything (using dot **.**) and then again anything, this time at least once (by using plus sign: **+**).

Summing this together we should get exactly the kind of logic You requested.

Comment: "testing Lettuce" will not be matched

Comment: But now "testing L" will be matched

Comment: That's it I think, I've marked yours as the correct one since it is extremely short (kind of spectacular), feel free however to extend a little bit the answer briefly explaining the rule, at least I would appreciate it :)

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer that the commas are important, so that "testing L" doesn't have to be matched

Comment: I would trimm quotation marks before matching, for simplicity of it. I think they are noice here.
But if You are unable to do this - I have edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a lookahead based regex to fail the match if "testing " is followed with `L` and 0+ whitespaces before the end of the string:

```
/^"?testing\s+((?!L?\s*"?\s*$).*?)"?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI8cY2/4)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `testing` - a literal string `testing`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `((?!L?\s*"?\s*$).*?)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as few as possible (due to the lazy `*?`, to account for the trailing `"` later) but only if not equal to `L` (1 or zero occurrences) or whitespaces followed with the end of string (`$`) and `\s*"?\s*` will also account for the optional trailing `"`
- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `$` - end of string.

So, the `(?!L?\s*$)` negative lookahead will fail the match if "testing " is followed with:

- end of string
- `L`
- whitespaces
- `L` and whitespaces...

And optional `"`.

```js
var ss = [ '"testing rest"', '"testing what"', '"testing Loong"', '"testing N"', '"testing L"', '"testing"', '"testing "' ]; // Test strings
var rx = /^"?testing\s+((?!L?\s*"?\s*$).*?)"?$/;   
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + ((m = ss[s].match(rx)) ? m[1] : "NONE") + "</b><br/>";
}
```

And if you just want to avoid matching a "testing " string with `L` at the very end (before optional `"`) you may shorten the pattern to

```
/^"?testing\s((?!L?"?$).*?)"?$/
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI8cY2/7) (the `\s` is replaced with a space in the demo since the test is performed against a multiline string)

Comment: I added `"?\s*` to the lookahead, and now it should account for the optional `"` at the end.

Comment: Considering that in my particular case the spaces are not that optional, this simplified version also works ^"?testing ((?!L?"?$).*?)"?$ so thanks a lot, it's taken a while to understand it :)

Comment: However, the answer from @T.Z. also works and we will agree it is definitively clearer to write and understand ...

Comment: I would not be that sure, it matches the `testing` with `L` - https://regex101.com/r/wI8cY2/8. The point is that T.Zz regex does not account for optional `"` - I am not sure they should be accounted for anyway.

Comment: Well, I've implemented your solution to my code since yours is the only one that works completely, so thanks a lot and I re-mark yours as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex that you want. It matches string starting with testing then one or more space characters then word characters that are atleaset 2 or more in size.

```
/^testing\s+\w{2,}/
```

Comment: I didn't mean to match a string of 2 or more letters, I meant to avoid matching the specific letter L (now clarified in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this](https://regex101.com/r/cW1dK1/2) is the regular expression you're looking for:

`/^"(testing(?: )?.*)"$/`